# Chi-Square test with relative values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, permutation-test

I am working with a weird data set and it is driving me crazy.

Survey respondents (a,b, c,...) were asked to each **distribute 15 points** among **3 different **preferences****. Accordingly, every preference can have 0 to 15 points, but the points must be 15 in total. Now I want to test whether the two groups A and B have different a preferences or not.

Can I simply aggregate the totals of all points for all categories and then test for difference with a Pearson Chi-Square test (see example below)?

Or does the data entail relative values as every preference can only have 0-15 points which prohibits the use of Pearson Chi Square? I am super confused....

Example:

**Raw data:**

| Respondent | Preference 1 | Preference 2 | Preference 3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 5 | 5 | 15 |
| b | 8 | 2 | 5 | 15 |
| c | 7 | 4 | 4 | 15 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Table for Chi-Square:**

| Group | Preference 1 | Preference 2 | Preference 3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A (a+b+c) | 20 | 11 | 14 | 45 |
| B (d+e+f) | 18 | 10 | 17 | 45 |

Answer (score 0):

The chi-squared test for homogeneity in a contingency table would **not** be appropriate here. You do not have a table of independent counts! It seems to me that each respondent, which distributes somehow 15 points over three categories, represent one data point, which can be treated in a model as independent. No standard model or hypothesis test seems appropriate.

I would first decide one test statistic (and the chi-squared test statistic could be one possibility ...) and then maybe a permutation test.